# The div was empty when add headers on iframe to showing NextJS page

Tags: reactjs, http, next.js, postman

I want to add headers on iframe src like [this example](https://carstenbehrens.com/how-to-send-request-headers-iframe/).

Here is my code:

```
 <iframe></iframe>
  <script>
    async function getSrc() {
      const res = await fetch("https://mynextjsapp.com/login", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "token",
        }
      });
      const blob = await res.blob();
      const urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute("src", urlObject)
    }
    getSrc();
</script>
```

Unfortunately, it blank and showing nothing. Then when I trace that, it because the content inside div with id `__next` is empty when I fetch that NextJS page:

[image: postman]

The content inside div with id `__next` should it look like this:
[image]

when I use iframe like this `<iframe src="https://mynextjsapp.com/login"></iframe>` there is no issue, the div is not empty:
[image]

Is anyone can explain?or have a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's because you're using postman at the first screenshot. And the postman does not run JavaScript needed to render HTML elements for that empty div. Postman just shows the row answer from the server. You need a browser to get js executed

Comment: I think your right, I try fetch a page on my other ReactApp with ajax and postman. Then the content is contain a text like this: "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." @AlanSvits